# How to anagram digit in python?

Tags: python

What is my problem ? I want act inverse number--example : 123 ==>321

```
def loop(a):
    i=0
 while(a>=1)
       print(a%10)
       s=s/10
       i=i+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has a few problems, aside from the indentation and the missing colon.

First of all your are using `print` which automatically adds a line break, so that might not be what you want the result to look like. You could store the result in a string which you append the latest character to and then print it once at the end.

Further, you are using a variable `s` which was never used before. In thise case it should be `a` as you want to strip off the last digit using an integer division by 10. Note that in this case, this will only work like that in Python 2, as Python 3 will use a float division there (e.g. `15 / 10 == 1.5`). You can prevent that by explicitly using the integer division there (this will also make your intend more clear): `s = s // 10` (note the two slashes).

Lastly, you are incrementing the variable `i` without ever using it, so you can just get rid of it.

In the end, it might look like this:

```
def reverse (a):
    rev = ''
    while a > 1:
        rev += str(a % 10)
        a = a // 10
```

---

A shorter solution, utilizing the fact that you can just reverse strings:

```
>>> num = 123
>>> rev = int(str(num)[::-1])
>>> rev
321
```

If you leave out the `int()`, you can even keep trailing/leading zeros and get a string instead:

```
>>> num = 3210
>>> str(num)[::-1]
'0123'
```

Answer (score 1):

Few issues:

- Your indentation does not match. [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) suggests 4 spaces for indentation.
- You're missing a colon after `while(a>=1)`
- Although this isn't an issue, you don't need the parentheses in the while loop, it can just be `while a >= 1`
- `s = s/10` might not return what you expect. For example, `12/10 == 1` (unless you're dealing with floats here).

---

This can all be simplified using slicing:

```
>>> print int(str(123)[::-1])
321
```

Comment: Actually `s/10` (the integer division in Python 2; or `s//10` in Python 3) would be what OP wants—except that it should be `a`, not `s`.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to indent correctly. (And don't mix tabs and spaces.)

```
def loop(a):
    i = 0
    while a >= 1:
        print(a % 10)
        a = a / 10
        i = i + 1
```

You were also missing a colon after the `while` condition.